# Update HTML file using java api

Tags: java, html

I have an HTML file that needs to update on the fly. Basically, I want to populate that HTML file based upon the details fetched from Database. Now I don't know how to update the HTML using any java API.

Example:

```
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sample File</h1>
    <p>
        <span class="abc">abc</span>
        <span class="description"> Sample Document</span>
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="label">Title</th>
            <td>Sample Value</td>  
    </table>
</body>
```

Then Updating:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="label">Title1</th>  <-------------- Updating the table value
        <td>123</td>  
</table>
```

Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Comment: java or javascript ? what did you try?

Comment: i used java tried using jsoup didn't get any success

Comment: What you need is "templating", google for it.

Comment: @luk2302 can you tell me more about this. I will start looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to constantly update the data on the page, without reloading it. Pay your attention to EventSource (js).

```
const source = new EventSource(url);
source.onmessage = function (e) {
handleResponse(e);
};
```

And on the java side it uses a controller that returns stream.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkData", method = {RequestMethod.GET}, produces = "text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8")
...
return "data:" + data + "\n\n";
```